# select near duplicates with trailing slashes

Tags: mysql, sql, trim

I have a large database of URLs, and I have duplicates from trailing slashes.  I would like find duplicate values of those ending with a trailing slash, but not urls with text after the trailing slash, such as `http://www.google.com/asdfasdf`

```
CREATE TABLE link_info (
  id INT,
  url VARCHAR(32)
);

INSERT INTO link_info VALUES
(1, 'http://www.yahoo.com/'),
(2, 'http://www.google.com/'),
(3, 'http://www.google.com/asdfasdf'),
(4, 'http://www.yahoo.com');
```

And I am trying to select duplicates without the trailing slash, but it selects `http://www.google.com/asdfasdf` as a duplicate.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(TRAILING '/' FROM url) url
FROM link_info
```

I was hoping to use regexp, but that doesn't work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(TRAILING REGEXP('[/]$') FROM url) url
FROM link_info
```

Comment: Are you trying to select duplicates or get a distinct list? For duplicates, I think you want to use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

Comment: So the desired output would be only 1 row, yahoo.com, count = 2? It isn't 100% clear what your desired output is.

Comment: @AgRizza Initially I wanted to select both, but returning only 1 duplicate also works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query will return every url trimmed. I think you need something like this:

```
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '/' FROM url) trimmed_url
FROM link_info
GROUP BY trimmed_url
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT url)>1
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81038/25).

**Edit**

If there are no exact duplicates, and you just want to keep the row with no trailing slash, you could use this delete query:

```
DELETE l1.*
FROM
  link_info l1 INNER JOIN link_info l2
  ON l1.url = CONCAT(l2.url, '/')
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8829/1). Notice that this query will just remove the duplicated yahoo.com with the trailing slash, but it won't remove the trailing slash from www.google.com/

Comment: hehe you used my fiddle :) , but its wrong this solution , he want have google also,

Comment: @echo_Me I cut&paste the code, so it happens to be the same fiddle :) but I don't think the OP wants google because they are two different urls, both yahoo url are the same so they need to be returned

Comment: i think he want delete the link after google and return one link with google as duplicate.

Comment: @fthiella You are right, I would like to return the yahoo url.
echo_Me haha yeah, i used your fiddle.

Comment: Do I update if I want to delete the selected duplicates after?
`Update TRIM(TRAILING '/' FROM url) trimmed_url
FROM link_info
GROUP BY trimmed_url
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT url)>1`

Comment: @Murdrae you want to update the row and remove the trailing slash? or you want to delete the row and just keep one without duplicates?

Comment: @fthiella Delete the row and just keep on without duplicates

Comment: @Murdrae but what if you have multiple duplicates? e.g. two rows with yahoo.com/ and two rows with just yahoo.com? can it happen?

Comment: @fthiella no, there are no exact duplicates.

Comment: @fthiella this is awesome, how would I go deleting the URL without the trailing slash?

Answer (score 1):

you may use this

```
 SELECT  TRIM(TRAILING '/' FROM url) url
 FROM link_info
 group by SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '.com', 1)
```

But this works only whith links which have `.com` so with `.net` or `.something` you add a 
union

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81038/22)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select *
  from link_info
 where url in
       (select url
          from link_info
         group by case
                    when replace(url, substring_index(url, '.', 1), '') like '%/' then
                     replace(url, substring_index(url, '.', 1), '')
                    else
                     concat(replace(url, substring_index(url, '.', 1), ''),
                            '/')
                  end
        having count(*) > 1)
```